# Does this JavaScript function have a linear or quadratic time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I'm trying to get my head around this solution in a Google interview video: https://youtu.be/XKu_SEDAykw?t=1139.

Though they say it is linear in the video, I'm not 100% certain if (and why) the entire solution is linear rather than quadratic?

Because the `find()`/`includes()` method is nested in the `for` loop, that would make me assume it has a run-time of `O(N * N)`.

But `find()`/`includes()` is searching an array that grows 1 step at a time, making me think the run-time in fact just `O(N + N)`?

*Here's my version of the solution in JavaScript:*

```
const findSum = (arr, val) => {
  let searchValues = [val - arr[0]];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let searchVal = val - arr[i];
    if (searchValues.includes(arr[i])) {
      return true;
    } else {
      searchValues.push(searchVal);
    }
  };
  return false;
};
```

My workings:

- When `i = 1`, `searchValues.length = 0`
- When `i = 2`, `searchValues.length = 1`
- When `i = 3`, `searchValues.length = 2`

Shouldn't that imply a linear run-time of O(N + (N - 1))? Or am I missing something?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you'd use a `Set` for `searchValues`, that would be linear.

Comment: As @JonasWilms notes, a set makes the function linear because the `find`/`includes` operation would be O(1). The linked video uses a set, but your version of the solution uses an array, so your version would be quadratic while it could (should) be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is quadratic, because as you mentioned `.includes` traverses the array, so does `for`. In the interview however they talk about an `unordered_set` for the lookup array, which implies that this could be implemented as a HashSet, which has O(1) lookup/insertion time, making the algorithm O(n) (and O(n²) worst, worst case). The JS equivalent would be a `Set`:

```
 const findSum = (arr, sum) =>
  arr.some((set => n => set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n))(new Set));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and new solution, Jonas. Time for me to look a bit deeper into sets!